# Pre-process the intent before sending to LUIS

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using LUISDialog to communicate with luis and added business logic for each intent. During actual conversation, LuisDialog sends the utterance directly to luis and returns the result to my method. 
For a use case, I need to pre-process the utterance before the dialog sends it to LUIS. Is there a way to interrupt and add pre-processing logic?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did Ezequiel's answer help solve your question?

Comment: YES it help. thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the [GetLuisQueryTextAsync](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L259-L262) method, that is the method responsible from extracting the utterance out of the message.

The text obtained from that method is then being sent to Luis (as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L202-L204)).